# When dragging file onto a HTML page, how do I stop them from opening up in full?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have an `<input type="file" multiple />` on my page, styled as a drag and drop area, however, when a file isn't dragged into this input field and its dropped elsewhere on the page, how can I stop them from opening up in full?

Thank you.